# Telegram bot security suggestion

Tags: authentication, one-time-password

I'm developing a Telegram bot trough which I can remotely control some parameters of my computer, such as turn on/off the display, lock (but not unlock) the screen, mount and unmount drives, etc.

In order to prevent somebody else to gain control of my computer, the bot checks the sender's username and it only executes the commands if it matches mine. However I would like to make the bot more secure, by using some kind of authentication before executing every command.
Of course I could simply prompt for a password, but that would not be secure as I would have to send it in plain text, and basically any person who sees my messages could have it. So I thought about something like a one-time password I can mentally calculate. Here's an overly simple example to let you better understand: the bot asks me for the password, and it tells me a random word from a wordlist. Then I check the current time; if it ends with a even digit, the password will be a synonym of the word; while if it ends with an odd digit, the password will be the opposite of that word.

So, if for example the bot sends me "easy" and it's 12.32, I reply "trivial". If the bot sends me "dark" and it's 09.47, I reply "bright".
I know this isn't good at all: it's quite easy to guess, words can have more than one synonym, etc. So I'm asking you if you can suggest me a similar (but hopefully better) algorithm, so that I can mentally calculate one-time passwords to easily but securely authenticate myself with my bot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your system relies on security through obscurity. It assumes that the eavesdropper doesn't know your system. When the attacker does know it, it's pointless. And you just posted your system on the internet, so it is already compromised.

A common two-factor authentication system which doesn't rely on any alternative authentication channel or electronic gadgets is using a TAN (Transaction Number) list.

1. Generate a list of numbered random transaction numbers
2. save the list where your program can read it
3. Print it out and keep it in your pocket
4. When you give a command, the server responds with the number of the TAN it expects ("please enter TAN #47")
5. You look up the number on your list and enter it

Every TAN must only be used once, no matter if your reply is correct or incorrect.

Alternatively you could just use a more secure messaging system with a more trustworthy user authentication.

Or just use [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) to remote-control your computer.

Answer (score -2):

Nice r/a system.
Maybe a wordlist with multi complex words and hex ?
r: frog ?
a: spadefoot toad
passwd : Spadefoot746f6164

r: 1942 ?
passwd : george6f7277656c6c